# Can I retrieve a GitHub PR review status via the API?

Tags: github, github-api

I do not want to retrieve the review's "state" ( e.g., 'open', 'closed' ) but rather the status (e.g., 'approved'). I cannot see a way to do this through the API however. It always returns an empty JSON array, regardless of the status.

For example, this *_should_* return a status of "approved", but it returns nothing:

https://github.mydomain.com/api/v3/repos/myOrg/myRepo/statuses/8675309

results in:

[

]

Is this operation ('review status') not supported through the API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should actually be trying a different API. According to the [Status API documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statuses/) of GitHub,

> The status API allows external services to mark commits with an `error`, `failure`, `pending`, or `success` state, which is then reflected in pull requests involving those commits.

So the **Status API** provides the status of every commit as part of a PR, for eg, if the build failed or succeeded as part of the commit push. The below request would only return the statuses as part of a reference.

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/commits/:ref/statuses
```

What you need is the **Reviews API**, where you can get the reviews for a PR, which would have the `state` field that you are expecting. The API is

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/pulls/:number/reviews
```

And a sample response is

```
[
  {
    "id": 80,
    "node_id": "MDE3OlB1bGxSZXF1ZXN0UmV2aWV3ODA=",
    "user": {
      "login": "octocat",
      "id": 1,
      "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjE=",
      "avatar_url": "https://github.com/images/error/octocat_happy.gif",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/followers",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/following{/other_user}",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/gists{/gist_id}",
      "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/subscriptions",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/orgs",
      "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/repos",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/events{/privacy}",
      "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/received_events",
      "type": "User",
      "site_admin": false
    },
    "body": "Here is the body for the review.",
    "commit_id": "ecdd80bb57125d7ba9641ffaa4d7d2c19d3f3091",
    "state": "APPROVED",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World/pull/12#pullrequestreview-80",
    "pull_request_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/pulls/12",
    "_links": {
      "html": {
        "href": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World/pull/12#pullrequestreview-80"
      },
      "pull_request": {
        "href": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/pulls/12"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Note that the **state** field in the response has the **APPROVED** state that you are looking for.

More info on the same in the [GitHub documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/reviews/#list-reviews-on-a-pull-request) of Reviews API.

Comment: OK great - Thanks for the info!  It looks like that will do it!